# facebook access token that never expires have limited permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an facebook application and generated token from Graph API Explorer (expires 1 hour). When I use that Token to view information about a page's information, the token shows everything including Facebook Likes count `likes` as:

```
{
   "id": "561485583979241",
   "about": "smmadmin.com is your complete social media marketing partner which makes you go global with high engagement and interaction over your online profile.",
   "can_post": true,
   "category": "Internet/Software",
   "checkins": 0,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "577141705746962",
      "offset_x": 61,
      "offset_y": 0,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10623331_577141705746962_2427585332498063845_o.jpg",
      "id": "577141705746962"
   },
   "has_added_app": false,
   "is_community_page": false,
   "is_published": true,
   "likes": 1678,
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/smmadmin.official",
   "name": "Social media marketing administrator",
   "talking_about_count": 4,
   "username": "smmadmin.official",
   "website": "http://www.smmadmin.com",
   "were_here_count": 0
}
```

I exchanged the token to extend the token expiry using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=MY_CURRENT_TOKEN
```

Now when I use this token to view the page's information, that shows me the limited information only as:

```
{
   "name": "Social media marketing administrator",
   "id": "561485583979241"
}
```

Spent my whole day but got nothing. Any idea?

Comment: sounds like a bug, you should file a report. btw, extended user tokens DO expire, after 60 days. there is no user token that is valid forever.

Comment: May be. 
You can generate token that last forever. Check this:
https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/

Comment: i specifically said "user token", and those are never valid forever. make sure you understand the difference between the tokens (app token, user token, page token).

Comment: page tokens are not useful to get likes count of other page?

Comment: they are, but you never talked about page tokens in your question, you are only dealing with user tokens as it seems. more information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

User access_token's expiry will be set to never ,once your app gets approved I guess.Again it's limited to certain permissions.